# Copy shipment data from canceled order to the new one on edit

Tags: shipment

anyone one knows how to duplicate/copy shipment data with status from canceled order to The new one on edit? When i edit order my shipment data os reset to default status. I override The paynent methods to copy data and its ok but shipment os wrong. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, just load the shipment data, clone it (check wether everything is cloned recursive), unset the ID, change the order id and save it :)